Matplotlib, update one a point but not the whole plot

Hi!
How do I update only the red point in my plot? I can only get it to add more points.
The goal is to able to hover over the graph and the dot follows the line (closest cordinates to the x-axis of the mouse on the line). I don't want to update the whole graph since I want to use this on much bigger graphs and it starts to lag.
Here's the code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.artist as art
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [3, 5, 8]
y = [9, 8, 4]

current_point = []

ln, = ax.plot(x, y, '-')

def update(frame):
    if frame.inaxes == ax:
        x_mouse = frame.xdata

        passing = True
        if passing:
            current_point = ax.plot(0, 0, "ro")
            passing = False

        print(f"before remove current_point: {current_point}\n")
        current_point[0].remove()
        print(f"after remove current_point: {current_point}\n")

        idx = np.argmin(np.abs(x - x_mouse))
        #x_closest gets the time from x index and minus time before x-cordinate 0.
        x_closest = x[idx]
        y_closest = y[idx]

        current_point = ax.plot(x_closest, y_closest, "ro")
        ax.draw_artist(current_point[0])

        fig.canvas.blit(ax.bbox)

fig.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', update)

plt.show()

